# Where to get job listing for a job board for a niche?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, linkedin-api

I am thinking to add a job board to my website to show all recent Computer Science positions. I looked at a few options like web scraping. but it will cost a lot. Is there any free or low cost option to access to the job listings? I found the Indeed API is not accessible any more.

https://developer.indeed.com/docs/publisher-jobs/job-search

Answer (score 1):

There are some free and low-cost options to access job listings.

1. You can use CareerJet API, Adzuna API, Google Custom Search API where you can retrieve job listings for your job board. In most cases you need to sign up with them to retrieve job postings.
2. You can use RSS feed.
3. You can also partner with those job listing companies.